# JSON.parse error: unexpected character after project release

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-ajax

I used jquery.unobtrusive-ajax in my view.
In this view, there is a form that is submit via ajax.

In the action if the modelsets is invalid, I will return the errors through the code below

```
 Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
 return Json(new { errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors) });
```

And in the view through the code below I show the errors to the user.

```
        function failed(err1) {
        obj = JSON.parse(err1.responseText).errors;
        console.log(obj);
        EmptyValidationErrors();
        jQuery.each(obj, function (i) {
            //alert(obj[i].ErrorMessage);
            AddValidationError(obj[i].ErrorMessage);
            ShowValidationErrors();
        });
    }
```

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Try `console.log(err1.responseText)` to check the json response returned by the controller action

Comment: err1.responseText
"Bad Request"

Comment: But in localhost return:
"{\"errors\":[{\"Exception\":null,\"ErrorMessage\":\"Message text\"}]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CustomErrors mode

It's IIS behavior to handle responses whith 400 http code. So, you need to remove that line

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

and add extra data to your response. like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
  return Json(new { success = true });
}

return Json(new { success = false, errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors) });
```

And read this in your JS code like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
    if (!data.success) {
      $.each(data.errors, function(i, error) {
         AddValidationError(error.ErrorMessage);
      });
      ShowValidationErrors();
    }
  }
});
```

In your `Web.config` you can find section like that:

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
```

`mode="Off"` rewrite to `mode="On"` during deploy process, so in production any responses whith 400 code handle by another way, than while debugging. In `Web.Release.config` you can find what exactly rewriting in this section

### Update

Another solution:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return Json(new { errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors) });
```

This will stop handling custom error `mode="On"` and resposne will contains your json with errors.